# Why does IE restrict the JavaScript files of local HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Why does IE restrict JavaScript files from working when we open a local html file? The message says:

"To help protect your security, Internet explorer has restricted this web page from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer. Click here for the options"

Can anyone tell me how get get rid of this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want to run in the Internet zone add this to your HTML source:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

If you want to run in the Intranet zone add this to your HTML source:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

Either will stop the message from displaying and allow JavaScript to execute.

This will also allow the file to open on other PC's without having to change Internet Explorer options.

Comment: Great discovery - I found for it to work you must have the <html> tag on a separate line after the <!DOCTYPE><!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->. Anyway great way to stop that annoy message when you generate a local web page! THANKS

Comment: After editing my html file, I also had to close and reopen IE. Refreshing the page wasn't enough for IE to notice the MOTW.

Comment: Its not working for me. I have added the MOTW as explained above. Any idea about the issue ?

Comment: @AnishV The MOTW *must* be followed by a carriage return *and* a line feed (`0D 0A` in hex). If it's just a new line (`0A`) after the MOTW, it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

In IE, go to Internet Options.
Then 'Security' tab.

Set the 'local intranet' zone to low, and disable protected mode if on.

That should stop that message from being displayed. If that doesn't work, set a 'custom level' to allow javascript to run locally.