# c# Open and write to external browser from windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have a C# Windows form application and I need to open a a webpage that sends SAML off to a server with then does auth and redirects to the destination. Since the SAML I am writing/sending changes every time, I've been writing a simple file to the temp folder and opening it via the default browser. Internet Explorer doesn't like doing this and balks saying the content is blocked.

Is there any way I can, from a Windows form, open an external browser and write content to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
    <!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

in the html file I'm opening from the local temp folder and now IE opens it just fine.

Answer found from

[Why does IE restrict the JavaScript files of local HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146926/why-does-ie-restrict-the-javascript-files-of-local-html-pages)